# How to use sqoop to export the default hive delimited output?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a hive query:

```
insert override directory /x
select ...
```

Then I'm try to export the data with sqoop

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlm/site --username site --password site --table x_data --export-dir /x  --input-fields-terminated-by 0x01 --lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

But this seems to fail to parse the fields according to delimiter
What am I missing?
I think the **--input-fields-terminated-by 0x01** part doesn't work as expected?

I do not want to create additional tables in hive that contains the query results.

stack trace:

```
 2013-09-24 05:39:21,705 ERROR org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Exception: 
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9-2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
 ...
```

The vi view of output

```
16-09-2013 23^A1182^A-1^APub_X^A21782^AIT^A1^A0^A0^A0^A0^A0.0^A0.0^A0.0
16-09-2013 23^A1182^A6975^ASoMo Audience  Corp^A2336143^AUS^A1^A1^A0^A0^A0^A0.2^A0.0^A0.0
16-09-2013 23^A1183^A-1^APub_UK, Inc.^A1564001^AGB^A1^A0^A0^A0^A0^A0.0^A0.0^A0.0
17-09-2013 00^A1120^A-1^APub_US^A911^A--^A181^A0^A0^A0^A0^A0.0^A0.0^A0.0
```

Comment: Yes **--input-fields-terminated-by 0x01** part is not working correctly.
You can try this:

**sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlm/site --username site --password site --table x_data --export-dir /x  --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N'**

Comment: @MukeshS the delimiter '\001', didn't work for me, instead '\0001' worked. The extra '0' did the trick

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the correct solution for that special character in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# ... your script
hive_char=$( printf "\x01" )

sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlm/site --username site --password site --table x_data --export-dir /x  --input-fields-terminated-by ${hive_char} --lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

The problem was in correct separator recognition (nothing to do with types and schema) and that was achieved by hive_char.

Another possibility to encode this special character in linux to command-line is to type Cntr+V+A

Comment: you could also simply the octal representation of ^A '\001'. sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlm/site --username site --password site --table x_data --export-dir /x  --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n'

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
--input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

as flags in the sqoop export command seems to do the trick for me.

So, in your example, the full command would be:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlm/site --username site --password site --table x_data --export-dir /x  --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

Comment: Question: how do you know it's '\001' instead of '\01' or '\1'? I checked the manual: https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_inserts_vs_updates 
but didn't find any introduction on how to input by ASCII code...

Answer (score 0):

I think its the DataType mismatch with your RDBMS schema.

Try to find the column name of "9-2" value and check the datatype in RDBMS schema.

If its int or numeric then Sqoop will parse the value and insert. And as it seems "9-2" is not numeric value.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like sqoop is taking '0' as a delimiter .
You are getting an error because:-
First column in your mysql table could be varchar and second column is a number.
As per below string:-

16- **0** 9-2 **0** 13 23^A1182^A-1^APub_X^A21782^AIT^A1^A0^A0^A0^A0^A0.0^A0.0^A0.0

Your first column parsed by sqoop is :-**16-**
and second column is:-**9-2**

So its better to specify a delimiter in quotes('0x01') 
or

(Its always easy and has better control)use **hive create table** command as:-
create table tablename row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' as select ... and specify '\t' as delimiter in your sqoop command.